# What are the usecases and benefits of using KubeVirt

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kubernetes

I am trying to explore a bit about KubeVirt (https://kubevirt.io/) which is an open-source sandbox project of CNCF. KubeVirt help in provisioning virtual machines inside a Kubernetes cluster along with containers.

My question is about the practical usecases of KubeVirt.

1. What is the benefit of running a VM inside a Kubernetes Cluster when you can simply create a VM in the cloud or use hypervisors like VMWare in an on-prem setup?
2. In what all industries is KubeVirt going to be useful/beneficial and how?

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the benefit of running a VM inside a Kubernetes Cluster

Offering a unified API managing regular Kubernetes workloads, and virtual machines. Kubernetes clients would be able to manage virtual disks and qemu/kvm virtual machines, while being subject to Kubernetes RBAC, quotas, through a well-known API, ...

Compared to vmware: you don't need Kubernetes end-users being able to log into vmware/vsphere.

Compared to bare-metal: you may not have had any automation allowing end-users managing virtual machines.

> In what industries is KubeVirt going to be useful/beneficial and how

Now that's a good question. Only time would tell.

So far, I can't tell any of my customer either plan to or do use this.

I've been testing it for fun myself, it works. I could see it may be useful hosting solutions that are not easily container-izable into Kubernetes (eg: mail server appliance, that would in part require root privileges, with lots of pieces, ... maybe something that's not open source and could not easily be broken down into containers).

Now why would I put such an appliance in Kubernetes rather than import it into an existing KVM hypervisor ... I'm not sure we can justify this by "having a single API to manage it all". As a cluster operator or application owner, troubleshooting such appliances in Kubernetes adds some complexity.